# Optimize the code for dataframes in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Below is the code for checks on two columns. I know this isn't the proper way of doing it on two columns of a dataframe but I was hoping to get help for doing it in a better way

```
     for i in range(len(df)):
         if df['Current_Value'][i].lower() == 'false'or df['Current_Value'][i].lower() == '0' and df['_Value'][i].lower() == 'false' or df['_Value'][i].lower() == '0':
             df['CHECK'][i] = True
         elif df['Current_Value'][i].lower() == 'true' or df['Current_Value'][i].lower() == '1' and df['_Value'][i].lower() == 'true' or df['_Value'][i].lower() == '1':
             df['CHECK'][i] = True
         elif df['Current_Value'][i].lower() in df['_Value'][i].lower():
             df['CHECK'][i] = True
         else:
             df['CHECK'][i] = False
```

Comment: It's best if you post an sample input dataset and the expected outcome. This makes it easier to understand what you're doing and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lambda expressions for such a check. Although you haven't provided us with a sample dataset, what you could do is something like this:

First define the lambda function

```
def fill_check_column(current_value, value):
    # Precompute this, so that it is calculated only once
    current_value = current_value.lower()
    value = value.lower()

    if current_value in ['false', '0'] and value in ['false', '0']:
        return True
    elif current_value in ['true', '1'] and value in ['true', '1']: 
        return True
    elif current_value in value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then use it on the data frame:

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda row: fill_check_column(current_value=row['Current_Value'],
                                                     value=row['_Value'],
                       axis=1)
```

You could also improve the `fill_check_column` to make the checks only once.